# Python says: "expected an indented block"

Tags: python, shell, cmd, stack, indentation

I've been playing around with Python a bit recently and have come across this error when creating functions. I can't seem to fix it :(. CODE:

> ## Python

```
#Python

 choice = input('Append Or Write?')    
  if choice == "write":
    def write():
     pass
         text_file = open('WrittenTXT.txt', "w")
         type_user = input('Type: ')
        text_file.write(type_user)
        text_file.close()

if choice == "append":
    def append():
# Making a txt file
#Append
pass
text_file = open('WrittenTXT.txt', "a")
user_int = input('Enter An Integer: ')
 space = "\n" * 2
lines = [space, "Hi\n", "Hallo\n", "Bonjour\n", user_int]
text_file.writelines(lines)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: is this part of a function? hard to tell. remember in python, indentation defines scope. your first line (starting with `choice`) isnt' aligned with the line directly below it. could be your formatting in StackOverlow, but i doubt it. go back through your code and make sure lines in the same scope are aligned.

Comment: Wrong formatted code is your issue. I refer you to read about Python's basics before asking obscure questions.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call your functions that you defined. `pass` may also be causing the statements in your function to get ignored, remove `pass`.

Reformatting your code:

```
#Python

def append():
        # Making a txt file
        #Append
        # pass
        text_file = open('WrittenTXT.txt', "a")
        user_int = input('Enter An Integer: ')
        space = "\n" * 2
        lines = [space, "Hi\n", "Hallo\n", "Bonjour\n", user_int]
        text_file.writelines(lines)
        text_file.close()


def write():
    # pass
    text_file = open('WrittenTXT.txt', "w")
    type_user = input('Type: ')
    text_file.write(type_user)
    text_file.close()

choice = input('Append Or Write?')

if choice == "write":
    write()
if choice == "append":
    append()
```

Comment: I think it would be wise to define the functions outside of the `if` blocks since this layout could be mistakenly interpreted that functions should be defined on the fly (which is what I imagine that the OP was thinking)

Comment: I agree, I tend to try and leave code as close to the OPs original, but you're right that could lead to misinterpreting best practices. will update, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything is sustaining perfectly well now because of you. I cannot thank you enough for your help - I have now got a working program which doesn't just say "Hi" lol. Many Thanks,